# Trying to prevent Jquery function to loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a drag and drop application using Jquery. All the functions are working properly but I'm using html.change for to enable the script for dropped items. The problem I have right now is depending on how many changes I do to the HTML in the application it slows the application down.

This is the Javascript code I'm using

```
$(function() {
  $('html').change(function() {
    $(".checkdrop").change(function() {
      var checkdrop = $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.checkdrop').val();
      var textul = $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.textUL');
      var input = '<input type="text" placeholder="Value" class=""><br>';
      if (checkdrop >= 3) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.three').css("display", "block");
        $('th.three').css("display", "table-cell")
      }
      if (checkdrop >= 4) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.four').css("display", "block");
        $('th.four').css("display", "table-cell")
      }
      if (checkdrop >= 5) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.five').css("display", "block");
        $('th.five').css("display", "table-cell")
      }
      if (checkdrop >= 6) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.six').css("display", "block");
        $('th.six').css("display", "table-cell")
      }
      if (checkdrop >= 7) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.seven').css("display", "block");
        $('th.seven').css("display", "table-cell")
      }
      if (checkdrop >= 8) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.eight').css("display", "block");
        $('th.eight').css("display", "table-cell")
      }

      if (checkdrop == 2) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.three,.four,.five,.six,.seven,.eight').css("display", "none").val("")
      }
      if (checkdrop == 3) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.four,.five,.six,.seven,.eight').css("display", "none").val("")
      }
      if (checkdrop == 4) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.five,.six,.seven,.eight').css("display", "none").val("")
      }
      if (checkdrop == 5) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.six,.seven,.eight').css("display", "none").val("")
      }
      if (checkdrop == 6) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.seven,.eight').css("display", "none").val("")
      }
      if (checkdrop == 7) {
        $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.eight').css("display", "none").val("")
      }
    });
  });
});
```

If I put an alert in the end of the "checkdrop" it will be triggered the same amount of times as the amount of changes I've done to the HTML.

Is there a way to make this easier and prevent the code from looping?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because you keep binding the events.... Why do you have the html change() ?

Comment: Many improvements to make. Most importantly: don't keep re-attaching the handlers. And rather than all the if statements, use a switch or an else if.

Answer (score 0):

When a look your code, i see one problem.

why you need see all html ?

the performace goin down

```
  $('html').change(function() {
```

remove method find() of jquery, because ride and all dom elements its not good to performace

i dont know your html, but try use [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) to find closest

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your solution, I dont know your HTML code structure, otherwise it may have leads optimized solution then this.

```
$(function() {
    $('html').change(function() {
        $(".checkdrop").change(function() {

            var checkdrop = parseInt($(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.checkdrop').val());
            var textul = $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find('.textUL');
            var input = '<input type="text" placeholder="Value" class=""><br>';

            var checkdrop_class={
                1: ".one",
                2: ".two",
                3: ".three",
                4: ".four",
                5: ".five",
                6: ".six",
                7: ".seven",
                8: ".eight"
            };

            current_class=checkdrop_class[checkdrop];
            $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find(current_class).css("display", "block");
            $('th'+current_class).css("display", "table-cell")

            for(var i=checkdrop+1;i<=8;i++)
            {
                $(this).closest('.labelDrop').find(checkdrop_class[i]).css("display", "none").val("")
            }
        });
    });
});
```